# Wait for template own Event to change Session for own Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, meteor

A Meteor client Template helper benefits from a Session reactivity to supply correct data to the browser.
The same template has a `click` event which modifies this Session thus expecting some changes in the browser, then it modifies the "new" display using jQuery.

The problem is that jQuery does not wait till the DOM is ready with the new display, thus the said session reactivity has not finished its magic.

How to approach this problem?  Thanks

```
Template.checks.helpers({
  'values': function() {
    return Session.get('someVar');
  }
});

Template.checks.events({
      'click .checks-row': function(event) {
        Session.set('someVar', newArray);
        $('li').each( do things);) //<---- ops, the old list items still there
        }
      });
```

```html
<template name="checks">
  {{#each values}}
  <ul class="checks-row">
    <li>{{this.label}}</li>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: If you need actually need to use jQuery (you are initializing a plugin or something), then use a separate template for the list items. In that template's `onRendered` callback, do your jQuery work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible I suggest refraining from using jQuery for this. Hopefully you won't need it:

1. Since you're setting value you'll know what they are if you need to read them.
2. If it's rendering, perhaps the template / blaze code can be altered.

Going away from jQuery has a a couple benefits:

1. You don't have to wait on the DOM
2. Protects from an inconsistent DOM state (Blaze won't be aware of what jQuery is doing).

P.S. [Getting away from Sessions is a good idea too](https://github.com/dferber90/eslint-plugin-meteor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-session.md)